# Node JS Express JS: Create a model framework to interact with RESTful API layer?

Tags: node.js, rest, model-view-controller, orm, model

I am creating a new NodeJS ExpressJS application in which I want to separate out the web client and the services layers. I have created a services layer using ExpressJS and MongoDB.

Now I want to create a model layer in my web client, that will interact with the API end points exposed by the services layer. I have so far explored Backbone as an option, as it has models built in, but it seems a little excessive, as Backbone comes with a bunch of bundled VC features.

Is there a lightweight model library.framework that can be used to do three things:

- Create Models
- Make REST calls to the API layer
- Support ES6 promises

I realize this is kind of subjective, but I think this is an issue a lot of first time architects face, so TIA!